# What's the best way to translate «undeveloped countries»?

Tags: перевод, phrase

If we are to translate it literally we'll get «неразвитые страны», but this has even more negative connotation for some russian speakers than «страны третьего мира» for which «undeveloped countries» acts almost like a euphemism.

I did come up with «страны не прошедшие стадию развития», which doesn't sound like an insult but is a little longish.

Comment: "Страны с большим потенциалом развития" :)

Answer (score 7):

It seems that Wikipedia doesn't make a difference between terms 'undeveloped countries' and 'developing countries'. I never heard Russian equivalent of 'undeveloped countries'. So why not use the Russian equivalent of 'developing countries': **'развивающиеся страны'**?

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `слаборазвитые страны`.
See this article in Wikipedia:
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Развивающиеся_страны](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B). The search for "undeveloped countries" in the English Wikipedia redirects to the article "Developing countries" which is the English counterpart of the article I gave the link to above.

Answer (score 0):

The literal translation of `underdeveloped countries` would be`недоразвитые страны` which is even worse. I would use `страны динамичного развития` or `динамично-развивающиеся страны`.

Comment: That's a good translation, but it has positive connotation, rather than a neutral one. Undeveloped doesn't mean the same as developing.

Comment: "Динамично развивающиеся страны" - 20 years ago I think it would be the term for Hong Kong, Singapore, South Korea, and Taiwan (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Asian_Tigers), for instance).

Answer (score 0):

You can say "Страны третьего мира" - third world countries

Comment: It is a bit outdated nowadays. "First world" was US and Western Europe, "Second" - USSR and Eastern Europe and "Third" - all other countries. Since "second" is now missing, all conception is now broken.

Answer (score -1):

слаборазвитые страны
and backward translation - south